# reading multiple files results in consecutive files receiving "Permission denied"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

When using the concatenated syntax to input a list of files into a program, the first file seems to not error out but then the rest of the files after the first get the error "Permission denied". It doesn't matter what the first file is, I could set the last file of the list as the first input and it gets accepted but everything after this gets the "permission denied" error.

Any ideas?

I have checked folder permissions and set chmod for this folder to 755 but the problem persists.

```
RAW_DIR=/gpfs/ts0/projects/Research/sequencing/H0243/01_raw_reads/
FILES=`ls -m ${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_14_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_14_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_15_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_15_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_16_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_16_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_31_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_31_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_33_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_33_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_34_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_34_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_36_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_36_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh1_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh1_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh2_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh2_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh3_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh3_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh4_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh4_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_nc1_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_nc1_r2.fq.gz| sed 's/ //g'`
```

I am expecting the files to be read in one by one successfully but at the moment all files read in after the first successful file error out with "Permission denied".

Comment: have u tried with sudo privileges?? Maybe is related with `chown` command ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us more details. It is unclear what you mean with "input a list of files into a program". What is your expected result in variable `FILES`? Why do you use a manually created list of files? Is it a list of all files in `${RAW_DIR}`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to input all the files from ${RAW_DIR}, I'm not trying to execute them but input them into a separate program.

Comment: @YaseenAhammed You didn't answer my question how the result in `FILES` should look like. What do you want to do with the variable? Do you need all file names separated with `,` instead of space?  **Please add all information to your original question** instead of writing comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use pipe characters in the command

```
ls -m ${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r1.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r2.fq.gz|${RAW_DIR}3013_14_r1.fq.gz ...
```

you only pass the first file name as an argument to `ls -m` and you create a pipe.  That means the shell will connect the output of one program to the input of the next program.
The shell will try to execute `${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r2.fq.gz`, `${RAW_DIR}3013_14_r1.fq.gz` etc. as programs.

Most probably these files are not executable, that's why you get the error message. (The file doesn't have execute permission.) And most probably this is not what you want.

If you want to specify more than one argument (file name) to a program, separate the arguments with space.

Maybe you want something like

```
FILES=`ls -m ${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_12_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_14_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_14_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_15_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_15_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_16_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_16_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_31_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_31_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_33_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_33_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_34_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_34_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_36_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_36_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh1_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh1_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh2_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh2_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh3_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh3_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh4_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_mCh4_r2.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_nc1_r1.fq.gz ${RAW_DIR}3013_nc1_r2.fq.gz| sed 's/ //g'`
```

If you want all file names in `${RAW_DIR}` you can use

```
FILES=$(ls -m ${RAW_DIR}*| sed 's/ //g')
```

or if you want to be more specifc

```
FILES=$(ls -m ${RAW_DIR}*.fq.gz| sed 's/ //g')
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense!!